# Shell script partially sourcing functions

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I have a shell script am sourcing in the format . custom_functions.sh. It has worked well in the past but there is this one machine, where it is partially sourcing the functions and leaving out others. I am using it on hp prodesk running Ubuntu 18.04.

**Additional Information**
I have a several custom functions for quick formatting, installation etc in one file (called custom_functions.sh).  I normally source this file into other other scripts for re-use. Here is a a portion of the file:

```
# !/bin/bash

# custom_functions.sh

. colour.sh

function commaToSpace()
{
    sed -r 's/,/ /g'
}
function hyphenToCamel()
{ 
    tr '_' '\n' | awk '{printf "%s%s", toupper(substr($0,1,1)), substr($0,2)}'
}
function camelToHyphen()
{
    sed -r 's/([A-Z])/_\L\1/g'
}
function hyphenToSentence()
{ 
    tr '_' ' ' | awk '{printf "%s%s", toupper(substr($0,1,1)), substr($0,2)}'
}
function spaceToCamel()
{ 
    tr ' ' '\n' | awk '{printf "%s%s", toupper(substr($0,1,1)), substr($0,2)}'
}
function lowerCase()
{
    tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
}
function properCase()
{
    tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=""}{$1=toupper($1);print}'
}
function stringSortDropDuplicatesNums()
{
    string=$(awk '{print !a[$0]++}' <<< "$1")
    printf '%s\n' "${string//[[:digit:]]/}"
}
function trimString(){
    tr -d '\040\011\012\015'
}
.
.
.
```

**Only a number of these functions*** are being sourced by other scripts in the said machine and the remaining towards the end of the file are skipped. If I rename this file and source it, then all the functions are included. Notice, I have ensured there are no name clashes. This phenomenon has only been observed in a specific machine, and other types of the same machine running the same operating system have no problem. Thanks.

Comment: I do not have much experience in scripting but i feel your question is too vague. Maybe show us the code or elaborate a bit on the circumstances of you issue.

Comment: Seeing the code could really help, but knowing what's different about the machine things are failing on versus the others would be good too.  Maybe there are different versions of `bash` or the failing machine may not have `bash` installed.